# Cannot see property using search api

Tags: rest

I tried to retrieve results from the search api using REST call like this: `http://server/Search/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'`

I can see the properties except one custom property I have in user profile, when I go to search results page, and edit the web part, I can see the property within the list of properties I can use to filter the results.

I have this property managed property in search configuration, mapped to user profile property, it's set as Searchable, Retrievable, Queryable, it's showing in results page to filter but I was unable to see it in REST.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a user profile property you also have to set security via user profile service so it is available to everyone.

**EDIT**:

- From Central Administration --> Manage Service Applications Find your
- User Profile Service Application and open it Under People --> click
  manage properties
- Edit your property and make sure policy setting is
  set for everyone.

I have not experienced this directly with REST calls but I did come across it while building display templates, which also rely on managed properties.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply, how do I do that?

Comment: Edit my reply with more info

Comment: Yes the policy already set to everyone.

Comment: After you created the property did you also update the result types?  There is sometimes a property sync message that is displayed after configuring custom managed property and you have to tell SharePoint to update it's result source (link is included in the message).

Comment: I was not the one who created this property, the guy who configured it is not there anymore. but even when I search without defining the scope to people, it doesn't show.

Comment: Look at your search settings - under result types.  If you need to do a property sync it will tell you.  Also, if a full crawl has not run after the property was created or changed you will not get results.

Comment: did not find the option..

Comment: Seems it won't work.. I don't know what to do

Comment: Look at this link - it shows the property sync. Also - double check which crawled property you are mapped too - if there are no results then there is nothing to show so make sure you are mapped to the correct property.  http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/12/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-results-option-2.aspx

Comment: thanks Jesus, the managed property is mapped to the right property, I think it should show although if it's empty but would show as null. seems like the properties are already in sync. and I have run the full crawl many times.